# Mini-Profiler using MiniProfilerEF.Initialize() - How to exclude a connection from being profiled

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I have a fairly common usage of Mini-Profiler in an MVC 3 project. I'm using the nuget packages:

- MiniProfiler - v1.9.1
- MiniProfiler.EF - v1.9.1
- MiniProfiler.MVC3 - v1.9.1

I'm setup to profile EF 4.2 Code-First, and that is actually working perfectly.

The problem is that the mini-profiler is also trying to wrap and profile a second SQL connection that my app uses for security Membership. I'm using the ASP.NET Universal Membership Provider with SQLCe 4.0 in this case. EF & code-first are not involved in this security connection at all, but every time I hit the security DB I get an exception from the mini-profiler.

So... how do I exclude a connection from being profiled when I've setup code-first profililng with MiniProfilerEF.Initialize()?

Comment: Exact same issue. I am using universal provider (but am using full SQL azure DB) and I get an error. Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: Not yet. I'll probably hack into the source myself eventually. It isn't a major problem since the exception isn't breaking the app in any way. It just an annoyance.

Comment: Seems like a normal sort of setup. Maybe developers will provide the functionality one day.